# Self-learning: Are Differential and Integral Calculus required before Multi-variable Calculus?

Tags: calculus, soft-question

I am a adult learner learning Calculus. I would like to know if it is a must to master Differential and Integral Calculus before moving to Multi-variable Calculus.

If I am not wrong, Differential and Integral Calculus are taught in high school and Multi-variable Calculus is taught in college?

Comment: Single- and multi-variable calculus each have a differential side and an integral side. In other words, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One would be remiss not to study differential and integral calculus before studying multivariable calculus. The meat of multivariable is completely untouchable without exposure to both of the single-variable subjects, and multivariable builds heavily on what is learned in single-variable calculus.

The topics covered in a multivariable calculus course include understanding the derivative and the integral in higher dimensions. These two are the bread and butter of multivariable, so one should be comfortable with the single-variable. The definitions in the multivariable setting draw motivation from the single-variable case, not vice versa.

Depending on your definition of mastery, you can start to get your feet wet with multivariable with some basic understanding of the single-variable derivative and integral. For instance, the definition of a derivative is similar in each setting and multivariable integration has nice geometric interpretations.

The only thing that can really be said here is *it's possible to make some headway with basic knowledge of single-variable calculus,* but you can only expect deeper connections and greater understanding to come once you have understood the single-variable subject in greater detail.

Comment: Is multivariable calculus taught in high school or college?

Comment: @youcanlearnanything Depending on the institution and the student, multivariable is generally taught in the first or second year of a student's program in college. Certain exceptional students may take multivariable calculus in high school. However, this is uncommon, and most students will take up to AP Calculus AB or BC while in high school.

Comment: What is AP Calculus AB or BC?

Comment: @youcanlearnanything The AP Calculus courses cover the basics of single-variable calculus for students in high school. They are roughly the equivalent of a complete single-variable calc sequence one would take in college. You can learn more by googling AP Calculus.